# Show inactivity Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I am working on a module that will log off my application if not active for 2 minutes.
After 2 minutes, I set the visible property of my form as false and show the log off screen.When user log on again I simply set the visible property of last active form as true.

Now **I am showing a form A and there is a button in this form that will show another form B as dialog box.**

When it is time to log off I simply set visible property of both forms(A, B) as false.And when user logs in again I set this property as true.

But problem is that form B is not showing as dialog now.

Also if in my login code, I set form B as

```
form b.ShowDialog();
```

It shows as a dialog but now the data entered into this form text fields (before logging off) is cleared.

Can somebody explain the reason for this behaviour?

I want to show form B as dialog and also want to maintain the status of fields in form.

**> EDIT**
This code is hiding the forms.

```
if (Program.issueDepositForm != null)//form B static reference Checking if form B is not null
{
    Program.issueDepositForm.Visible = false; //Form B
    Program.saleproduct.Visible = false;//Form A f static refrence
}
```

This code is showing them again

```
Program.saleproduct.Visible = true; //Form Astatic refrence
if (Program.issueDepositForm.Visible == false) //Form B
{
    Program.issueDepositForm.ShowDialog();      //Form B
    //Program.issueDepositForm.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: Care to share some code?

Comment: May be you should post whole code that is involved in the problem.. How you are showing second dialog, how you are hiding it and how you are showing first again

Comment: Do setting the visible=false; property of dialogue form change it,s dialogue behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When you set Visible to false, the form is closed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120708/c-winforms-showdialog-and-subsequent-show-on-form/5121243#5121243) suggests a workaround, which is to cancel the form closing so it is available to be re-shown.